# Sorting query_posts() with a complex orderby filter

Tags: wp-query, filters, mysql, query-posts

I'm trying to order my posts with a complex orderby scenario which uses the `CASE` and `WHEN` syntax. To achieve that, I've created a filter :

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'order_properties_by_reference', 10, 2 );
function order_properties_by_reference( $orderby, $wp_query ){

    global $wpdb;

    $orderby = "CASE 
                    WHEN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value BETWEEN 2000 AND 2999 THEN 1
                    WHEN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value BETWEEN 4000 AND 4999 THEN 2
                    WHEN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value BETWEEN 3000 AND 3999 THEN 3
                    WHEN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999 THEN 4
                else 4
                END";

    return $orderby;
}
```

And I've added this filter in my theme functions.php file.

Now, on a page of this theme, I'm trying to query the posts with this custom `orderby` filter with this code :

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
);


query_posts($args);
```

But the filter seems not to be used by the query. I'm sure I'm missing something, can you assist?

Comment: Note that querying posts via their post meta/custom fields is very slow/expensive. Additionally, you should never use `query_posts`, use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the parameters of the main query, don't create a replacement query with new parameters, at a minimum you're doubling the amount of work making the page twice as slow to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my issue. I was missing the `meta_key` param in the args of my `query_posts` function.

Here it is with the fixed version :

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'meta_key' => 'my_meta_key',
        'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
);
```